# Is this the right way to generate a wildcard CSR?

Tags: linux, openssl, ssl, https, amazon-linux

I generated my CSR on an Amazon Linux system using this command

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key ~/mymaindomain.com.ssl/mymaindomain.com.key -out ~/mymaindomain.com.ssl/mymaindomain.com.csr
```

I verified what I had done using

```
[davea@host mymaindomain.com.ssl]$ openssl req -noout -text -in ~/mymaindomain.com.ssl/mymaindomain.com.csr
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=US, ST=NY, L=New York, O=Main Co, OU=SubCo, CN=mymaindomain.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

Before I submit this to a CA, I was curious if this will match "www.mymaindomain.com" and "abc.mymaindomain.com."  I wanted to create a CSR that would match the "*.mymaindomain.com" expression but not quite sure if I did it right.

Comment: When it asked you for the common name, did you list it as *.mydomain.com or just .mydomain.com? If you have the wildcard listed as the common name, it should work. Doesn't look like your common name has a wildcard.

Comment: You didn't make it correctly, since there's no wildcard ( `*` ) appearing. Look with this example: `openssl s_client -connect stackexchange.com:443` look at the CN . CN=*.stackexchange.com there's a `*` for wildcard. It wouldn't match stackexchange.com , but if you get the certificate and decode it with `openssl x509 -noout -text` you'll see all the SANs: `DNS:*.stackexchange.com, DNS:stackoverflow.com, DNS:*.stackoverflow.com,` [...] `DNS:stackexchange.com` . Now you know what to do. And yes adding SANs with openssl is a bit painful, but I'm sure there are already Q/A about this

Comment: Thanks.  No I didn't make it with "*.mymaindomain.com" ... it was just "mymaindomain.com".  These comments give me exactly the answer I was looking for.